# I'm testing a function which is triggered when value is passed by HTML asynchronusly, i'm getting error as "expected false to be true"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test case in angular (jasmine/karma) where I pass value to function and check for return result is true or false.

.html

```
<div *ngIf="manageRole('issue')">manage role</div>
```

.ts

```
manageRole(role) {
    switch (role) {
        case 'admin':
            return true;
        case 'patient':
            return true;
    }
}
```

.spec file

```
it('should be true if admin', async() => {
    component.manageRole('admin');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.manageRole('admin')).toBe(true);
});
```

The above implementation gives me an error as "Expected false to be true".

I also tried multiple implementations where spy on, call through etc. but it is not giving me the proper results.

Comment: Sure you're using the correct method? Says `manageRole` in the ts while saying `manageJourney` in the spec.

Comment: @adldin Bradaric I've modified the question, if you have any suggestions please let us know.

Comment: @AkashAher , the above test case should work. the error "Expected false to be true" may be from some other test cases you have written. Check your console & CLI for any error. Fix your syntax error for the patient case. It should be return true; not return true: